# Shap interaction plots

Tags: shap, interaction-plot

I am applying SHAP on XGBoost regressor. I am trying to plot the interaction effects. But the summary plot is displaying only few variables. What to do in case of more than 10 variables?

I tried using "shap.summary_plot(shap_interaction_values, X)" but this is showing only 6 variables whereas I want it to show all the variables in the model which is 16.

Comment: Check out docs, you'll find answer to your question there

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `max_display` parameter yet?

Documentation: https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/shap.summary_plot.html

For example:

```
shap.summary_plot(shap_interaction_values, X, max_display=20)
```